# Set up mitmproxy in transparent mode on a docker container

Tags: networking, docker

Is it possible to turn a docker container into a gateway for a transparent proxy like [this](https://docs.mitmproxy.org/stable/howto-transparent-vms/)? I heard that you need to use macvlan or ipvlan, but what is the equivalent setup for the example shown in VirtualBox?